# Bootstrap difference in R2 between two models

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, r-squared, pseudo-r-squared

I apologise beforehand if this is already answered elsewhere, but I have searched for this particular question and didn’t find a post that matched it.

I have two logistic regression models: a base model `Y ~ X` and a full model `Y ~ X + Z`, for which I computed the pseudo R2. I want to estimate the difference in pseudo R2 between the two models to determine the added predictive value corresponding to variable Z, but using either cross-validation or bootstrap. The objective is to afterwards compare the added predictive value between several Z variables.

The thing is I am not sure how it should be done:

1. Use cross validation/bootstrap to compute the R2 for the base and full models in each fold, which are each averaged and then calculate the difference in R2.
2. Use cross validation/bootstrap to compute the difference in R2 in each fold, which is then averaged.